# Deadlock in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have been trying to resolve this deadlock for a while now with no success, its seems like the users are opening multiple tabs when executing this task. Below is the deadlock trace from red gate. Can someone assist

```
deadlock victim=process1bfa7651c28
  process-list
   process id=process1bfa7651c28 taskpriority=0 logused=676 waitresource=KEY: 15:72057739557339136 (3e550035b443) waittime=2214 ownerId=173025007 transactionguid=0xfbb95ce0cf74ab44a98a2a17c6a20332 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2019-10-14T12:12:39.823 XDES=0x1bf9b61c420 lockMode=RangeI-N schedulerid=16 kpid=5796 status=suspended spid=79 sbid=2 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2019-10-14T12:12:44.103 lastbatchcompleted=2019-10-14T12:12:44.103 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.103 isolationlevel=serializable (4) xactid=173025007 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=248 stmtend=1258 sqlhandle=0x020000004134de04324ea90259781aa68565de5ed013ea1f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
unknown     
     frame procname=unknown line=1 sqlhandle=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
unknown     
    inputbuf
(@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 int,@4 datetime2(7),@5 decimal(18,2),@6 int,@7 int,@8 varchar(100),@9 datetime2(7),@10 int,@11 int)INSERT [Finance].[PaymentSchedule]([fkEntityID], [C_EntityType], [fkPersonID], [C_PersonTypeCode], [DatePayable], [DatePaid], [Amount], [C_PaymentMethod], [C_PaymentStatus], [Reference], [CreateDate], [bRecon], [fkBankAccountID], [fkInstitutionAccountID], [fkCreateUserID], [fkReleaseUserID], [DateChanged], [fkUserChangedID], [fkParentID], [SplitPayment], [ProcInstID], [InitialAmount])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, NULL, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, NULL, @10, NULL, @11, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
SELECT [pkPaymentScheduleID], [VersionStamp]
FROM [Finance].[PaymentSchedule]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [pkPaymentScheduleID] = scope_identity()    
   process id=process1b747a4f468 taskpriority=0 logused=676 waitresource=KEY: 15:72057739557339136 (3e550035b443) waittime=3089 ownerId=173023610 transactionguid=0x37e282145f3ed340bc70dea8e82c11a4 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2019-10-14T12:12:38.727 XDES=0x1b4f2d10420 lockMode=RangeI-N schedulerid=16 kpid=6760 status=suspended spid=252 sbid=2 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2019-10-14T12:12:43.230 lastbatchcompleted=2019-10-14T12:12:43.230 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.230  isolationlevel=serializable (4) xactid=173023610 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=248 stmtend=1258 sqlhandle=0x020000004134de04324ea90259781aa68565de5ed013ea1f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
unknown     
     frame procname=unknown line=1 sqlhandle=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
unknown     
    inputbuf
(@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 int,@4 datetime2(7),@5 decimal(18,2),@6 int,@7 int,@8 varchar(100),@9 datetime2(7),@10 int,@11 int)INSERT [Finance].[PaymentSchedule]([fkEntityID], [C_EntityType], [fkPersonID], [C_PersonTypeCode], [DatePayable], [DatePaid], [Amount], [C_PaymentMethod], [C_PaymentStatus], [Reference], [CreateDate], [bRecon], [fkBankAccountID], [fkInstitutionAccountID], [fkCreateUserID], [fkReleaseUserID], [DateChanged], [fkUserChangedID], [fkParentID], [SplitPayment], [ProcInstID], [InitialAmount])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, NULL, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, NULL, @10, NULL, @11, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
SELECT [pkPaymentScheduleID], [VersionStamp]
FROM [Finance].[PaymentSchedule]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [pkPaymentScheduleID] = scope_identity()    
  resource-list
   keylock hobtid=72057739557339136 dbid=15 objectname=Finance.PaymentSchedule indexname=IX_PaymentSchedule_fkEntityID_C_EntityType_pkPaymentScheduleID_fkPersonID_DatePayable_DatePaid_Amount_C_PaymentStatus id=lock1b470862e00 mode=RangeS-S associatedObjectId=72057739557339136
    owner-list
     owner id=process1b747a4f468 mode=RangeS-S
     owner id=process1b747a4f468 mode=RangeI-N requestType=convert
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process1bfa7651c28 mode=RangeI-N requestType=convert
   keylock hobtid=72057739557339136 dbid=15 objectname=Finance.PaymentSchedule indexname=IX_PaymentSchedule_fkEntityID_C_EntityType_pkPaymentScheduleID_fkPersonID_DatePayable_DatePaid_Amount_C_PaymentStatus id=lock1b470862e00 mode=RangeS-S associatedObjectId=72057739557339136
    owner-list
     owner id=process1bfa7651c28 mode=RangeS-S
     owner id=process1bfa7651c28 mode=RangeI-N requestType=convert
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process1b747a4f468 mode=RangeI-N requestType=convert
```

Comment: Deadlocks will be common here due to the `SERIALIZBLE` isolation level. Consider  `READ COMMITTED` instead since the code here is reading the row just inserted so there is no need to block other concurrent inserts.

Comment: Do you have an index with leading column `pkPaymentScheduleID` to allow the `SELECT` to be seeked into efficiently? The deadlock is on a key in `IX_PaymentSchedule_fkEntityID_C_EntityType_pkPaymentScheduleID_fkPersonID_DatePayable_DatePaid_Amount_C_PaymentStatus` - which I assume has leading column `fkEntityID`

Comment: Changing the isolation level is not possible as this query is hard coded in the application somewhere. pkPaymentScheduleID is primary key so its a clustered index , should I add it as a key column as a non clustered index